# Intellij: Unable to properly stop java (spring boot) application

Tags: java, openjdk

I constantly need to press the stop button (the red square in Intellij) TWICE when stopping my spring boot application when it has been started inside Intellij.

When I press the second time it reports:

```
"Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"
```

And it stops.

**My system:**

```
Ubuntu:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Java:
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode)

Intellij:
2019.1.2 Community Edition.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, it is caused by excessive memory usage or related with an issue within multiprocessing. Can you track the memory usage and make sure that is not the issue